# Orientation bug with iOS 8 and Monogame?

Tags: xamarin, ios8, orientation, monogame

I´m creating a game in monogame and have recently updated my iPhone 4s to iOS 8. The game works fine on an Android device, but on the iOS device the game for the first of all won't start in landscape orientation,even if I have set it to start landscape only in the info.plist. However if i hit the home button on the iPhone and open the app again, then the game starts in landscape but I see that the battery indicator and the signal bar is still in portrait mode. So I think the game is in landscape but somehow my iPhone isn't. If i try to hit some of my buttons which are located to the right of the screen nothing happens and i get this error:

unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: ; layer = >

Here is a picture that describes my problem:
[image]

The game thinks it´s in landscape, but my iPhone is in portrait. Anyone have any idea to how I can fix this?

Edit: I probably should mention I´m making the game with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this pull request:

https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/pull/3116

Looks like there is now a fix. Downloading the PR and rebuilding Monogame.Framework.dll for iOS worked for me. They will soon have it merged with the main branch. Good luck!